# countin votes from a list in python

Tags: python-3.x

I want a code which counts votes from a list, for example, from this list `[jack , jack , mat , tom , tom , tom ]`, print count of each candidate:

Here is the code I tried but doesn't work:

```
votes = ['jack' , 'jack' , 'mat' , 'tom' ,'tom' , 'tom']
counter = dict()
for string in votes :
    if string in counter :
        counter[string] =+ 1
    else:
        counter[string] = 1
for this_one in list (counter.keys()) :
    print (this_one , counter[this_one])
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse your `=+` to `+=` (`=+` is basically the same as plain `=`):

```
counter[string] += 1
```

Or better, use a `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter(votes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```py
>>> votes = ['jack' , 'jack' , 'mat' , 'tom' ,'tom' , 'tom']
>>> counter = {el: votes.count(el) for el in set(votes)}
>>> counter
{'tom': 3, 'mat': 1, 'jack': 2}
```